# Find and classify singular points

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I've been asked to find and classify all singular points (removable, pole of order n, essential, or not an isolated point).  I am struggling with when infinity is a singular point and also how to recognize an essential singular point.  I have provided what I think the answers to the questions I'm struggling with are for the ones I think I know.  For the others, I am completely lost.

(a) $\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2}$

I got 2i, -21 are poles of order 2 since they are zeros of 1/f of order 2

(d) $\frac{z^2+1}{e^z}$

Is z = -infinity the only pole?  How do I find its type?

(e) $\frac{1}{e^z−1}$ − $\frac{1}{z}$

Do you combine them first?

(h) e$^{-z}$$cos\frac{1}{z}$

I multiplied this out to get that it = .5*(e$^i + e^-i$) so are there no singularities?

(k) sin ($\frac{1}{cos\frac{1}{z}}$)
I found that cos($\frac{1}{z}$) does not have an isolatged singularity at z = 0.  Does that help here?  Does it have isolated singularities at z = $\frac{1}{.5(n*pi) + n*pi}$? since \frac{1}{cos\frac{1}{z}} never exceeds one, is there a singularity when cos is 1 aka at $\frac{1}{n*pi}$?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In complex analysis, one considers only one point at infinity, not $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ like they're used in real analysis. $\frac{z^2+1}{e^z}$ has an essential (isolated) singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFischer . And its an essential singularity because if you find the Laurent series there are infinitely many terms of the form z$^{-n}$, n>0?

Comment: No, at $\infty$ it's the positive powers of $z$ that determine the type of singularity, and there are infinitely many of those with nonzero coefficients in the MacLaurin series of $(z^2+1)e^{-z}$.

Comment: Alright thank you @DanielFischer